Is this wall parallel with truss load bearing?
I have a studio vault type of truss in a section of my second story. I would like to remove a wall and im not sure if the wall would be load bearing. The first picture is a home in my same tract home development which has done this.


The wall itself might not be load bearing, but the end/edge might be, covering a support post.
